# What is the unit V/V?

Tags: amplifier, current-measurement, units

I came across this when I was browsing through the data sheets for a current sense amplifier such as the [LT6100](https://www1.elfa.se/data1/wwwroot/assets/datasheets/lt6100_eng_ds.pdf).

It reads:
"Fixed gains of 10, 12.5, 20, 25, 40, 50V/V are obtained by simply strapping or floating two gain select pins"

Does it really mean, for example 10V per V (10V/V)?

PS. Hmm it kind'a make sense. if 10V/V means that I get out 10 times higher volt (10 times amplification). Please confirm...

Comment: You should read a little about classical control theory, and something they call "Transfer Functions". The V/V unit is literally a gain transfer function of Volts out, given volts In

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it really mean, for example 10V per V (10V/V)?

Yes, it does. For every volt the input increases or decreases by, the output increases or decreases by 10 volts. Until it comes near the rails, of course. Note that this amplification is continuous; an input increase of 0.25V will result in an output increase of 2.5V, etc.

Comment: Yes, so Vout = Vin*10 for a 10V/V and Vout = Vin*12.5 for a 12.5V/V and so on...

Comment: Technically it's Vout = Vin * 10V/V, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Gain is a dimensionless quantity .The plots of input voltage to out put voltages are commonly used to find the transfer characteristics of a Device or circuit or a control system .For example in CMOS inverter we use the same for finding the point at which input voltage is high enough so that the circuit act as an inverter .The curve is very use full in this case to find the metastability state .
But you can see some times gain represented in decibels ,there also decibels is nothing but the logarithm of gain multiplied by a number ,in case of power its 10log(gain) and in case of voltage it is 20 log(gain).

Answer (score 0):

Although gain is a dimensionless quantity, a circuit with non-constant or partially-reactive input and output impedance would have different gain under different circumstances.  Specifying the gain in "units" of V/V, or else using the term "voltage gain", is a way of saying that if certain aspects of how the amplifier is used are fixed, the gain will be relatively constant even if other aspects vary.  In particular, if the amplifier is driven with a source impedance that is sufficiently low, the load impedance is sufficiently high, and the frequency is within certain limits, the gain will be within a certain tolerance of a specified constant value; even a 1,000-fold change in source impedance or load impedance wouldn't particularly affect it, nor would a change in frequency anywhere between the minimum and maximum limits (if the minimum frequency extends to DC, a 1,000-fold change in frequency would have minimal effect provided the maximum was not exceeded).

Note that if a device has constant voltage gain, its current gain ("units" of A/A) would vary greatly with the load impedance (cutting the load impedance in half would, within limits, double the current gain), and would could also vary greatly from one device to another or be highly sensitive to frequency (e.g. if the magnitude of the device's input impedance might be 10 megohms at 10Hz but only 1megohms at 10KHz, its current gain at the higher frequency might be 1/10 that at the lower frequency).  It would be possible to build a device whose current gain was relatively constant over a wide range of input and output condition, but the voltage gain of such a device would then be highly variable.

While it would be possible for the manufacturer to precisely specify how the current gain of a device with nearly-constant voltage gain would be affected by conditions, or vice versa, it's often much easier (and generally about as useful) for the manufacturer to simply specify whichever form of gain is closest to constant, and the conditions under which it will remain within a certain tolerance.